# JavaFX Webview and HTML Entities

Tags: html, webview, javafx

I've done very little HTML... and my question is quite simple. I am using the JavaFX WebView as a "chat container". The problem is that all the HTML special characters will be displayed as entities, and I'm confused as of how to fix this. For example, if I type `>` in the "chat box", which will append the text into the WebView, `&gt;` will be displayed. Am I missing something obvious here?

Answer (score 0):

Oh well, embarrasing to resolve the issue within 15 minutes of posting a question... anyway, the problem was that I used JSoup, and I received the text via `node.toString()` when I should've called `node.text()`. Problem solved.

Comment: Nice to see it solving it yourself, I have also used webview in my chat application because i was about to display emojies and chat bubbles :-)